# "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)" though method requires two parameters

Tags: ruby, arguments, jruby

I have a MiniTest like this:

```rb
describe Message do
  describe "#is_getting_unavailable" do
    let( :message ) { Message.new() }
    it "should be false when user does not exist in the database" do
      message.handle
      assert_equal(false, message.is_getting_unavailable)
    end
  end
end
```

Running this gives me complaint from `assert_equal`:

```rb
Message::#is_getting_unavailable#test_0001_should be false when user does not exist in the database

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
    test/unit/message_test.rb:148:in `(root)'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1703:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2209:in `send'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617:in `each'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617:in `each'
```

I did not understand this, so I included the test (just before the call of `assert_equal`):

```rb
  puts method(:assert_equal).inspect
  puts method(:assert_equal).arity
  puts method(:assert_equal).source_location.inspect
```

The output is:

```rb
#<Method: #<Class:0x1d1e394d>(Minitest::Assertions)#assert_equal>
-3
["/home/rjung/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/gems/minitest-5.0.6/lib/minitest/assertions.rb", 155]
```

So the method is correct, and the `arity` is correct. What's the issue here?

We also use `rr`, `timecop`. Any other questions, that could help me find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while, but I could narrow the problem down to this failing test:

```rb
require 'minitest/autorun'

describe 'Message' do
  let( :message ) { Hash.new }

  it "should not fail awkwardly" do
    assert_equal false, message.nil?
  end
end
```

The output of this test is

```
  1) Error:
Message#test_0001_should not fail awkwardly:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
    test/unit/message_test.rb:7:in `(root)'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1703:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2209:in `send'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617:in `each'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617:in `each'
```

So I filed a Bug for https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/343.
**Minitest does have a method `message` that was overwritten**, so don't use `message` as a variable.

What I still wonder is, why the stacktrace says the wrong number of arguments happen in `message_test.rb:7`, because the method that takes no arguments (`message`) is definitive called from somewhere else.

Comment: This will not happen any more. There's a [changeset](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/commit/13c8d891a416f409b04d7e99974870f019aa40b2) that warns you, if you try to overwrite a method like I did.

Comment: You (very likely) just saved me hours of head-desking. Thanks!